# Sent Eth from MetaMask wallet to new address

Tags: metamask

I sent eth from my MetaMask wallet, 0xDa79E751c4886D9691bC5ce61f7afe7468602a6B, to another address a year ago. I forgot I sent it and mistakenly thought it was still on MetaMask. The address I sent it to is 0xB6959A36378dDF9527087DDE49B9968488Dd0819. I would appreciate any help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your question and title are not clear, it's hard to understand what you need help with.

Do you want to get your sent ETH back? The answer is **no**.
You can't revert your txs, it's probably gone, unless you have contact with the recipient asking them to resend it.

Comment: I removed it from my MetaMask wallet, and sent it I’m assuming to an address or exchange where I could swap coins more easily. My problem is I don’t remember which exchange I sent it to. I wasn’t sure if I could find out which exchange it was given the transaction ID. Thanks!

Comment: @KadenMiller It is essentially impossible to determine which exchange or wallet is which exchange or wallet it is by looking at the address. If you are the owner of both addresses, you should find your saved data, emails, used exchanges and wallets. Only then will you be able to access the account you once owned. I see the transaction txs here but it can't tell where that receiving address was generated from: https://etherscan.io/tx/0xec73697a1589108cde73c4414bde260d0780af5d3704d910c01f92d2bc4045e8